# How can I create a django celery worker and delete it after my use?

Tags: python, django, celery

How can I create a django celery worker and delete it after my use? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the documentation:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#additional-commands

You can shutdown all workers or a specific worker with the 'shutdown' remote control command.